# SocketAsyncEventArgs.Completed doesn't fire in Windows 8

Tags: .net, windows-8, asyncsocket, iocp

When I compile this code on a machine with Windows 7 Ultimate and .NET 4 installed, it works just fine but when I try it on one with Windows 8 RTM and .NET 4.5 installed, Complete event never fires.

```
class Program
{
    private static Socket _Socket = new Socket(
        AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        SocketType.Stream,
        ProtocolType.Tcp);

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _Socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5012));
        _Socket.Listen(100);

        var arguments = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        arguments.Completed += OnAccepted;
        Accept(arguments);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Accept(SocketAsyncEventArgs args)
    {
        args.AcceptSocket = null;
        if (!_Socket.AcceptAsync(args))
            OnAccepted(null, args);
    }

    private static void OnAccepted(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Accepted.");
        Accept(e);
    }
}
```

The interesting thing here is if I put a breakpoint at this line and debug it:

```
var arguments = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
```

And connect this server using [Hercules](http://www.hw-group.com/products/hercules/index_en.html) before continuing execution, it works like a charm. I do this at the start and then magically, OnAccepted gets called and writes "Accepted." to the console on every single connection. I use the same code and same program (Hercules) on the machine with Windows 7 and .NET 4 but it always works.

- Am I doing something wrong?
- If not, is it a known bug of my OS or .NET Framework version 4.5?
- Can anyone reproduce this?

**Edit**: Both operating systems are 64 bit.
**Edit 2**: I reported this as a bug on Microsoft Connect, [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/759913/socketasynceventargs-completed-doesnt-fire-in-net-framework-4-5).
**Edit 3**: Found a workaround and post it to Connect (Simply by creating a fake, first connection).
**Edit 4**: If anyone can reproduce this, please join the issue in Connect.
**Edit 5**: I saw the [question Thomas has mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12464185/704144) and I tested whether `Console.ReadLine` was causing this or not. Turned out it was. If I add `Thread.Sleep(3000)` **before** my `Console.ReadLine` call and make a connection attempt in 3 seconds after I run the program, it works like a charm. Again, the odd thing is that I need to do this only once before calling `Console.ReadLine`. If I make one connection before calling `Console.ReadLine` then every consecutive connection works, even after `Console.ReadLine` is called. I'll mention this in the Conect page.
**Edit 6**: I added the link to the other question to the Connect page and added another workaround that involves calling `Thread.Sleep` before calling `Console.ReadLine` like I mentioned in the above edit.

Comment: Have you checked this isn't just a firewall / etc thing? Does it work with Socket.Accept? (my point here: is the issue with AcceptAsync, or is it with networking generally?)

Comment: @Marc: Accept works. AcceptAsync works too, but only if I try to connect _before_ calling AcceptAsync. The weird thing is doing that fixes everyting. All subsequent connections work without a problem if I just put a breakpoint after Listen and before AcceptAsync. When the execution stopped, I just connect to that socket using Hercules and hit F5: Bang, every subsequent connection works like a charm.

Comment: I'm not clear on one thing, in the instance where `Completed` never fires, OnAccept is still being called?

Comment: @Peter: No. AcceptAsync returns true so code doesn't call OnAccepted synchronously and new connections doesn't fire the Completed event, so OnAccepted is not being called in that instance.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464185/windows-8-issues-with-tcp-sockets-on-local-network-client-server-on-same-mach 
Will join on Microsoft Connect

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks, I updated this one after I saw your question and I'm going to update the issue in Connect in a minute.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue targeting .Net4 with VS2012 and running things on Win8RTM.  In order to get AcceptAsync task to complete, I have to activate/switch to the window containing the server process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a Windows 8 bug. Best workaround I could find so far is to start the IOCP operation on a different thread.

So the thing I should do in the code sample that is given in the question is changing this line:

```
Accept(arguments);
```

To this line in the `Main` method:

```
Task.Run(() => Accept(arguments)).Wait();
```

This prevents `Console.ReadLine()` call to block the IOCP operation.

<s>*As a side note: This is just a workaround to an operating system bug which will most likely be fixed via an update and -hopefully- making this workaround redundant.*</s>

This issue is fixed with the latest version of Windows 8.

---

**Edit:** Status of the [feedback item I have posted in Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/759913) is changed to "By Design".
I also received an e-mail which contains the following:

> The underlying issue for this behavior has to do with how IO
>   Completion Ports are handled in Windows 8.  .NET works using the
>   completion ports; when their behavior changed, so did the .NET
>   behavior.

**Edit 2:** Status of the feedback is changed again to "Active" with no details.

**Edit 3:** The feedback received another answer from Microsoft, stating:

> The latest version of Windows 8 should have this fixed. Note that it's an OS issue, not a .NET issue: you need to make sure you have the latest version of the OS. No changes were made to .NET to either cause or fix this issue."

Comment: is there an official Microsoft bug report that anyone could track publicly?

Comment: @mizi_sk: There is none I could find. I found a MS Connect link that's mentioned in [this TechNet Forum post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserver8gen/thread/5764cd0f-fda1-4cfa-ae35-808210bae77e) but it doesn't work anymore. In the same page Len Holgate commented the Microsoft's response as "We've passed this to the base OS team and they will consider this for a future update. I'm resolving this postponed." so there is no exact date or an active bug report to track afaik.

Comment: @mizi_sk: They closed the case, saying that this behavior is by design.

Comment: @mizi_sk: The issue is fixed with an update to Windows 8. I've edited the answer with the details.