# Can a Windows 8 Store App communicate with a Windows 7 Desktop App through UDP/TCP sockets?

Tags: windows, sockets, networking, websocket

To elaborate on the situation: We have two apps, lets call them A & B for simplicity. Both developed and running on Windows 7 and they can connect & communicate just fine using UDP/TCP. Now we want to convert App B to Windows 8 to take advantage of the Metro UI. Will we need to make extensive changes to the networking code in App A? Can it even continue to run on Windows 7 and yet communicate with App B running on Windows 8? From what I understand Win8 handles sockets a bit differently than the previous Windows, hence my doubt.

Comment: I don't see any reason why this should not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will we need to make extensive changes to the networking code in App A?

No, you don't need to change anything in A.

> Can it even continue to run on Windows 7 and yet communicate with App B running on Windows 8?

Of course.

> From what I understand Win8 handles sockets a bit differently than the previous Windows.

There are [some differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12145378/704144) between Windows 7 and Windows 8 when it comes to IO completion ports but no, I don't think it would be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Just to come at this from a different angle, communication is technically possible but [explicitly forbidden](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx) (assuming you want to publish your app in the Windows Store):

> 3 Windows Store apps behave predictably
>
> 3.1 You must use only the Windows Runtime APIs to implement the features of your Windows Store app
>
> We describe these APIs in the Windows Store apps API reference. Your app may only depend on software listed in the Windows Store.
>
> **Windows Store apps must not communicate with local desktop applications or services via local mechanisms, including via files and registry keys.**

If this is something that you'll be side-loading for enterprise use then disregard this answer.

Comment: We don't intend to publish to Windows Store, but thanks for the info anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why this should not work.

I already had Windows 8 metro apps which communicate with a server using sockets, and for testing purposes I also ran that server on the windows 8 machine while having the metro app connect to 127.0.0.1. It worked flawlessly.